# Android (API 10) Fragment error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a problem with running SupportMapFragment on Android (API 10) here is what I get from  logcat:

```
02-22 02:16:09.516    1132-1202/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.calendar.wid
02-22 03:50:54.214  15767-15767/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService has leaked IntentReceiver com.clockworkmod.billing.ClockworkModBillingClient$8@4054cb08 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService has leaked IntentReceiver com.clockworkmod.billing.ClockworkModBillingClient$8@4054cb08 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:756)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:551)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:817)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:804)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:798)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
            at com.clockworkmod.billing.ClockworkModBillingClient.checkPurchase(ClockworkModBillingClient.java:890)
            at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.Helper.checkClockworkBilling(Helper.java:334)
            at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.Helper.isPremium(Helper.java:359)
            at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService.checkForUpdates(DownloadService.java:624)
            at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService.onStartCommand(DownloadService.java:713)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2039)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:994)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 10:10:36.187    1132-1352/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.uplo
02-22 10:11:03.367    1132-1370/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:17:27.607   1038-11211/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:28.630    1038-1277/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:36.090    1132-1261/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:36.237    1132-4329/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:17:36.387   1038-14442/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:37.000  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:37.657  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:38.917   1038-14442/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:40.590  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010336
02-22 10:17:40.590  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010338
02-22 10:17:40.590  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101033a
02-22 10:17:40.590  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010359
02-22 10:17:40.697  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:41.527    1038-1038/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:41.737  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:42.130  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010336
02-22 10:17:42.130  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010338
02-22 10:17:42.130  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101033a
02-22 10:17:42.130  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010359
02-22 10:17:42.270  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:42.687   1038-11210/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:45.007  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:45.177  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:17:46.257    1038-1038/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:47.727    1038-1277/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:49.227   1038-11211/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:54.600    1038-1277/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:57.427    1038-1128/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:57.450   1038-11210/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:17:57.450   1038-11210/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:17:57.500   1038-19084/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:17:57.500   1038-19084/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:17:58.587    1038-1128/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:17:58.597    1038-1128/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:17:58.597    1038-1128/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:17:58.807   1038-19086/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:17:58.807   1038-19086/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:18:05.087   1038-11211/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:18:35.120    1132-1370/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:18:45.517  29533-29533/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ WEXT: STOP when iface is UP
02-22 10:18:45.887    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 0 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:18:45.887    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 2 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:18:45.887    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 3 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:18:45.887    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 4 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:18:45.887    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 5 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:18:48.017   1132-16702/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.uplo
02-22 10:18:51.717    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ Inititating Monitor
02-22 10:20:15.127    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ SPN: BA-EronetPLMN: ERONET
02-22 10:20:15.127    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ showspn: trueshowPlmn: false
02-22 10:20:15.127    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ Before Posting Intent, country_sim = BA   operator_Sim = Eronet
02-22 10:20:15.127    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ ShowSpn = true   Plmn = false
02-22 10:20:29.387    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:22:21.417    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:23:24.337    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ SPN: BA-EronetPLMN: ERONET
02-22 10:23:24.337    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ showspn: trueshowPlmn: false
02-22 10:23:24.337    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ Before Posting Intent, country_sim = BA   operator_Sim = Eronet
02-22 10:23:24.337    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ ShowSpn = true   Plmn = false
02-22 10:23:27.227    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:23:51.739    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ Inititating Monitor
02-22 10:24:35.767    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:24:57.237    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:26:27.237    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:27:12.567    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:27:57.237    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:28:05.117  29533-29533/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ ioctl[SIOCSIWSCAN]
02-22 10:28:07.317   1132-29539/? E/﹕ dhcp_do_request:: DHCP result prop_value is ok
02-22 10:28:07.317   1132-29539/? E/WifiStateTracker﹕ [dhcp handler] release sWiFiDhcpWakeLock
02-22 10:28:10.477    1132-1138/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:28:10.707   5456-19771/? E/TalkProvider﹕ replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! dvasic1@gmail.com, acct=1
02-22 10:28:10.707   5456-19771/? E/TalkProvider﹕ insert presence failed for account=1 username=dvasic1@gmail.com client_type=2 status= cap=0 priority=0 mode=3
02-22 10:28:20.707  29533-29533/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ WEXT: STOP when iface is UP
02-22 10:28:20.707    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 0 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:28:20.707    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 2 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:28:20.707    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 3 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:28:20.707    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 4 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:28:20.707    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 5 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:28:21.467    1132-1350/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.uplo
02-22 10:28:51.788    1331-1331/? E/SIM_STK﹕ Inititating Monitor
02-22 10:29:09.147  29533-29533/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ ioctl[SIOCSIWSCAN]
02-22 10:29:11.257    1038-1277/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:29:11.397   1132-29539/? E/﹕ dhcp_do_request:: DHCP result prop_value is ok
02-22 10:29:11.397   1132-29539/? E/WifiStateTracker﹕ [dhcp handler] release sWiFiDhcpWakeLock
02-22 10:29:12.860   5456-19974/? E/TalkProvider﹕ replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! dvasic1@gmail.com, acct=1
02-22 10:29:12.860   5456-19974/? E/TalkProvider﹕ insert presence failed for account=1 username=dvasic1@gmail.com client_type=2 status= cap=0 priority=0 mode=3
02-22 10:29:27.237    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:29:34.677  20019-20019/? E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Creating VM heap of size start:2097152 max:268435456 base:0x40011000
02-22 10:29:38.900  20056-20056/? E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Creating VM heap of size start:2097152 max:268435456 base:0x4002d000
02-22 10:29:41.477   1477-20061/? E/RJ﹕ START DB REFRESH
02-22 10:29:42.937  20074-20074/? E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Creating VM heap of size start:2097152 max:268435456 base:0x40011000
02-22 10:29:47.897  20105-20105/app.sercas.dev E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.sercas.dev/app.sercas.dev.map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
            at app.sercas.dev.map.onCreate(map.java:17)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/app.sercas.dev-1.apk]
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
            at app.sercas.dev.map.onCreate(map.java:17)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 10:29:51.557    1477-1477/? E/AllAppsWorkspace﹕ ***Start*** init Horizontal Grid View, instance id=com.lge.launcher.AllAppsWorkspace@405655b0
02-22 10:29:51.837    1477-1477/? E/AllAppsWorkspace﹕ ***End*** init Horizontal Grid View
02-22 10:29:52.607   1132-22422/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.partnerse
02-22 10:29:52.967    1132-1132/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.maps
02-22 10:29:54.137    1132-1380/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.googlequi
02-22 10:29:54.667    1132-1370/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:29:54.827   1132-22421/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.maps
02-22 10:30:09.857   1132-31400/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.lge.android.worldclock.w
02-22 10:30:09.907   1038-11210/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:30:10.127  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:10.127  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:11.208  15486-15486/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.ui.c.d', referenced from method com.facebook.ui.c.c.c
02-22 10:30:11.267  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:30:11.497   1038-11210/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:30:11.537   1038-11210/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:30:11.537   1038-11210/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.000000, delay 0
02-22 10:30:12.467  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.477  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.517  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.517  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.617  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.617  15486-20271/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
02-22 10:30:12.807   1038-11210/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:30:15.807   1038-20287/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 3, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:30:15.807   1038-20287/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setStreamVolume() for output 1 stream 12, volume 0.100000, delay 500
02-22 10:30:20.807  15486-15486/? E/ResourceType﹕ Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
02-22 10:30:21.090    1038-1128/? E/SuperExtractor﹕ File not supported
02-22 10:30:56.037    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:30:57.237    1132-1199/? E/Tethering﹕ active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
02-22 10:31:01.657  29533-29533/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ WEXT: STOP when iface is UP
02-22 10:31:01.697    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 0 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:31:01.697    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 2 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:31:01.697    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 3 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:31:01.697    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 4 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:31:01.697    1132-1269/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ not failing over to mobile type 5 because Mobile Data Disabled
02-22 10:31:04.377    1132-1138/? E/ActivityManager﹕ heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.google.android.apps.uplo
```

Activity:

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
}
```

map_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

EDIT:

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifestxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.sercas.dev"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-featureandroid:glEsVersion="0x00020000"android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
android:name="app.sercas.dev.map"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"android:value="AIzaS***********Fg0"/>
<meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.gms.version"android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have edited the file to include manifest file.

Comment: I see everything is right and i can assume you have installed Google Play Services, Have you tried in your map_view.xml file select all the file and then Ctrl+i for indentation, sometimes invalid characters are inserted. My conclusion is that the problem is the layout "Binary XML file line #2"

Comment: Yes I have installed the Google Play Services and I'm using android studio so the shortcut is not working but refformated the text many times now still no luck it's baffling :(

Comment: @DanielVasic post your manifest.xml file

Comment: Added I have added the Manifest file if you have any sugesstions it would be greatlly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work should read the log errors carefilly found this:

```
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 4.
```

So I changed the integer value on meta tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/gp_version" />
```

With the value 4030500 and now it works thanks @kaushik for the help if I had not read the logcat the right way wouldnt have found this :)

Answer (score 1):

u have to add this `permission` into ur `manifest file`

```
<permission
        android:name="app.sercas.dev.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="app.sercas.dev.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

I think this is u r missing.After adding this if ur problem is not solved then check ur `API-Key` is correct or not which u have generated using `ur computer's SHA-1 fingerprint;app.sercas.dev`.

Comment: Hey @kaushik I have added the perpissions still no luck and generated new API key again to confirm that is not the problem with this still no luck.

Comment: can u post the whole `logcat stack trace`

Comment: Ok, posted, Im using lg optimus p990 to test this  :)

Comment: have u changed `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: Yes I have now all of the sudden Gradle gives me some issues :(

Comment: I don't think it was related to that gradle ran out of heap so I restarted my computer, and it's fine now but the problem with the fragment still proceeds

Answer (score 0):

inside your `map_view.xml`, change:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

to:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for map_view.xml, works for me that way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".map" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This problem will be the end of me tryed almost everything and it doesn't work it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, other than that I have no idea what might be wrong too.